# Passing parameters through a web app using a personal domain

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a web app which is served on a personal domain using iFrame and passes various parameters.

gs file:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('test.html')
     .evaluate() 
     .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello world!
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>

google.script.url.getLocation(function(location) {
var parameters = location.parameters;
console.log(parameters.id);
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = parameters.id;
});

</script>
```

When using the webapp URL the output is:

**Hello World
1234**

When using the personal domain URL the output is:

**Hello World
undefined**

https://script.google.com/a/formapprovals.com/macros/s/AKfycbw3RWnpvnpqKUa1DL2iYzDUxFSBbdP9sW5llymWlgiqLlU8Ykza/exec?id=1234

http://example.com?id=1234

Help! this is driving me up the wall.

Comment: The `src` attribute in the iframe tag must include the search string parameters.  `<iframe style="margin-top:50px;" src="https://script.google.com/a/ajaddons.com/macros/s/published_ID/exec?id=1234"></iframe>`  You haven't shown your iframe tag.   If you want to put the search string into the URL of the site, and not the web app published URL, you'd need to get the search string with an "onload" function, change the `src` in the iframe and reload the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get and change the search string parameter from the domain search string with the following client side code in a script tag of your domain html, not the apps script web app html.

```
<iframe id="myIframe"
 src="https://script.google.com/a/macros/s/Published_Web_App_ID/exec">
</iframe>

<script>
  var loc = window.location.search;//Get the search string of the domain
  loc = loc.slice(1);
  console.log('loc: ' + loc)

  var params,theID;
  params = loc.replace("&",",");
  params = params.replace("=",'":"');
  params = '{"' + params + '"}';
  console.log('params: ' + params)

  params = JSON.parse(params);

  console.log('params: ' + params)

  theId = params.id.toString();
  console.log('theId: ' + theId)

  var myFrame = document.getElementById('myIframe');
  console.log('myFrame: ' + myFrame)

  var frameSrc = myFrame.src.toString();
  console.log('frameSrc: ' + frameSrc)
  console.log('typeof frameSrc: ' + typeof frameSrc)

  console.log('theId: ' + theId)
  var newSrc = frameSrc + "?id=" + theId;
  console.log('newSrc: ' + newSrc)

  myFrame.src = newSrc;//Set the new src and the iframe will refresh
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Sandy. I would have never got that on my own.